# How to show an validation error if there is no checkbox selected in the form on my CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, forms, checkbox

I have a simple form with multiple checkboxes and i want to know how i can show an error if there's no checkboxes selected?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the values returned to the action that are stored in the array $this->array .. and don't call the save() function until you validate it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check before the form is submitted. This you will need to do with javascript and to save effort, I suggest you use the jQuery validation plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

It's extremely easy to use and jQuery offers a lot for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Could always create a custom rule in you model for this behaviour. Or bind together a bunch of 'NOT_EMPTY' rules, then check the `$this->Model->validationErrors` array for errors.

Although I do think that creating a custom validation function in your model, then calling that using the regular Cake validation would be best. Be sure that all your checkboxes share a common name, as then they'll group together and make your life easier.